# Copies files and folders from one location to other using VB Script

Tags: vbscript

I have 2 folders name `FOLDER_ONE` and `FOLDER_TWO`,now I want to copy all the files and folders from `FOLDER_ONE` and paste them into `FOLDER_TWO` and want to rename this `FOLDER_TWO` to `FOLDER_ONE` .Can any one tell me how can I do this by using vbs  ???

Comment: You may not have meant to, but your question is effectively asking to merge two folders: copy all FOLDER1 files to FOLDER2, then rename FOLDER2 to FOLDER1, which deletes FOLDER2. Can you please clarify if this was your intention?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Run the following as a batch file:

```
move /-y "D:\example\original\*01*.txt" "D:\example\New folder\"

pause
```

The ***/-y*** is used to prompt if there are duplicates, and you can remove it if you don't care about over writing files.

This part ***"D:\example\original*01*.txt"*** we are defining the file(s) we will be moving. So in this example this will be any file that has **01** and **.txt** in its name. You will need to make sure you have the full path with “ “ around it.

This is where ***"D:\example\New folder\"*** we will be moving the file to. Once again make sure you have the “ “ around the full path if you have any spaces in the folder names.

Answer (score 0):

In batch files you have a few options depending on your needs:

- [`copy`](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb490886.aspx) – good for copying a few files around but better keep it simple
- [`xcopy`](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb491035.aspx) – better copy allowing copying whole directory trees with complex criteria as to what to copy and what not
- [`robocopy`](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc733145%28v=ws.10%29) – similar to `xcopy` but with additional emphasis on resilience and automation. Supports theoretically everything that `xcopy` does but sometimes with slightly varying semantics.

All of those have extensive online help and plenty of examples around the web.

Answer (score 0):

Why not just copy straight to `FOLDER_THREE`?

```
MD FOLDER_THREE
XCOPY FOLDER_ONE\*.* FOLDER_THREE /S
```